# How to create a stored procedure for select/update/delete statements

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures

I have this sql statement that I want to convert to store procedure. How can I do that?

```
select a.name, a.lastname, from myTable where b.name= a.lastname
```

Thanks

UPDATE
Would this be right guys

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure
AS
BEGIN
SELECT [a.name],
       [a.lastname]
FROM [myTable]
WHERE [b.name] = a.lastname
END
```

This is one of the code that I am really working on

sql statement

```
SELECT RTRIM(l.Lab1) + '/' + RTRIM(l.LabR) AS Lab, meta.Title,ls.[ID],ls.[surveyID], ls.[specialistID],ls.[isCompleted] FROM [MyDIM].[dbo].[lsLabSurvey] ls JOIN [MYDIM].[dbo].[dimDocMetaInfo] meta ON meta.id = ls.[surveyID] and specialistID = @PID and isCompleted=1 JOIN MyDatabase.DBO.PID_Table l ON ls.ID = l.ID
```

And My Attempted Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROCD1
AS
BEGIN
SELECT RTRIM(l.Lab1) + '/' + RTRIM(l.LabR) 
AS Lab, 
   meta.Title,
   la.[ID],
   ls.[surveyID],
   ls.[specialistID],
   ls.[isCompleted]
FROM [MyDIM].[dbo].[lsLabSurvey] ls 
JOIN [MyDIM].[dbo].[dimDocMetaInfo] meta 
ON meta.id = ls.[surveyID] 
and specialistID = @PID 
and isCompleted=1 
JOIN MyDatabase.DBO.PID_Table l 
ON ls.ID = l.ID
```

END

Comment: Sure there's an easy way to learn it. Try Google.

Comment: Which DBSM are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: I am using MS SQL... i have a whole bunch... was just trying to get a feel of it... it's not the actual statement juz a sample... so that i can go about doing it myself once I get the hang of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David said you are almost there but just need minor changes.

1. I suppose @Pid is a parameter,if so, it is missing from the Stored Procedure defintion.
2. The (and specialistId=@Pid and iscompleted =1) form the Where clause (Filter expression). So the procedure goes like this

`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROCD1 (@PID INT )
AS 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR,RTRIM(l.Lab1)) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,RTRIM(l.LabR)) AS Lab ,
                meta.Title ,
                la.[ID] ,
                ls.[surveyID] ,
                ls.[specialistID] ,
                ls.[isCompleted]
        FROM    [MyDIM].[dbo].[lsLabSurvey] ls
                INNER JOIN [MyDIM].[dbo].[dimDocMetaInfo] meta ON meta.id = ls.[surveyID]
                INNER JOIN MyDatabase.DBO.PID_Table l ON ls.ID = l.ID
        WHERE   ls.specialistID = @PID
                AND ls.isCompleted = 1
    END 
`
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks guys.. Dinesh and Prakash... that's just awesome... :)

Answer (score 0):

It's really not that hard. You're 95% of the way there.  The following is for SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SomeProcedureName  
AS  
select a.name, a.lastname, from myTable where b.name= a.lastname
```

---

And I highly recommend this book: http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/sams-teach-yourself-sql-in-10-minutes-ben-forta/1100070678

It covers basic SQL syntax, and gives examples for different "dialects" of SQL.  Each RDBMS has slightly different syntax for performing similar functions, and you will need to know the dialect of the DB you're working with.

Comment: It won't work with Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, Firebird, H2, HSQLDB, Derby, Vertica, Teradata, ....

Comment: While (nearly) all of them have a `CREATE PROCEDURE` the part that comes **after** that is completely different for every DBMS. Especially when the procedure/function has to return a result set (but given the fuzziness of the question, the answer is OK). I'm pretty sure the above statement will **not** run on DB2 unchanged.

Comment: Yep, you're right, the syntax is slightly different on each.  Thanks for giving me a reason to look it up.  Learning something new each day, and improving, is one of the main reasons I come here.

Comment: Thanks for your input david... could u please look at my updated post.